# Book on (character) voice

Tags: characters, character-development, resources, voice

Any book recommendations that teach you how to make sure each character sounds different in dialogue and is recognizable even without dialogue tags?
Any book tips to learn more about character development?

Comment: Are you looking for a book with formal guidelines for this or a reading recommendation for material where this is done well? Currently the question is somewhere in between but leaning towards the latter.

Comment: I'm looking for a book to learn this. I liked 'story engineering' to learn about story structure

Comment: Yeah I got that part but a book with formal rules for how it is done or a book that does it well that you can learn from by reading it?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Abidabiwriti.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  Glad to have you with us.

Answer (score 1):

[Dialogue (Elements Of Fiction Writing)](https://amzn.to/2ly2E4z) by Lewis Turco is an older book from Writer's Digest Press (F+W Publications) but it is really good.

I honestly read it in a day (it's not too long) and it provides a lot of good detail about getting character voices right and keeping them consistent.

Our understanding of a character in a novel often comes almost entirely from the things they say and this book does a good job of helping you learn how to set that up.